# How to display data in grid column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looping through one dataset.
The display output should be in columns, but it is coming in rows.

```
  <Grid direction="column" container >
       <Grid xs={6} item >
                {name}
       </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I am getting result like this:

```
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

I should be getting :

```
name1  name2
name3  name4
name5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this type of layout:

```
name1  name2
name3  name4
name5
```

You should remove direction="column" from your Grid container.

Check out my CodeSendbox to see solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-628op

Comment: Could you maybe make codesendbox and share link to it. Trying to solve your problem without seeing a bigger picture could be tricky...